# Sequelize CLI Not Finding Env Variables

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to run a db migration with the Sequelize CLI tool, but I'm running into an issue where my ENV variables are not being processed by the tool. In the github repo, it says in version 2.0.0 (I'm on 2.4.0) you can directly access ENV variables in `config/config.js` like so, process.env.DB_HOSTNAME, but I get an error that indicates that no values are being passed in from the variables

**Error:**

```
Unable to connect to database: SequelizeAccessDeniedError: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

**config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    "development": {
        "username": process.env.LOCAL_USERNAME,
        "password": process.env.LOCAL_PASSWORD,
        "database": process.env.LOCAL_DATABASE,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "dialect": "mysql",
        "migrationStorageTableName": "sequelize_meta"
    },
}
```

**.env:**

```
LOCAL_DATABASE="db_name"
LOCAL_USERNAME="root"
LOCAL_PASSWORD="test"
```

Comment: Are you using dotenv(https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) node module?
Are you able to connect db through username root and password test?

Comment: how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you forgot to require `dotenv` module:

```
require('dotenv').config();  // this line is important!
module.exports = {
"development": {
    "username": process.env.LOCAL_USERNAME,
    "password": process.env.LOCAL_PASSWORD,
    "database": process.env.LOCAL_DATABASE,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "migrationStorageTableName": "sequelize_meta"
},
}
```